# script to attach photos to form response

Tags: javascript, forms, upload

i have the code that will allow to browse files and upload to a form, but don't know how to get it to send the form with attachments (pics) to my email. help please?

Comment: What server-side technology are you using?

Comment: i'm basically putting up a personal website for my 25th reunion. using a free website (webs.com). is there some way i can do it within the html code? some kind of javascript?

Comment: btw, the javascript i already have is: <form id="imgForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data"> <p><label for="img0"><input type="file" id="img0" name="img0"/></label></p> </form>

Answer (score 0):

you can send email only on server side by php, perl etc. You should use `sendmail`

Comment: i'm basically putting up a personal website for my 25th reunion. using a free website (webs.com). is there some way i can do it within the html code? some kind of javascript?

Comment: btw, the javascript i already have is: <form id="imgForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<p><label for="img0"><input type="file" id="img0" name="img0"/></label></p>
</form>

Comment: no, you can't send email by javascript. You may ask support, sometimes they provides free url that sends on email all form data that you send